# What kind of fees can using an ATM incur that isn't a surcharge assessed for using an ATM to withdraw cash?

Tags: fees, atm

I read on [schwab.com](https://www.schwab.com/checking#:%7E:text=ATM%20surcharge%20rebates%20do%20not,from%20Visa%20and%20ATM%20operators.) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230113201958/https://www.schwab.com/checking#:%7E:text=ATM%20surcharge%20rebates%20do%20not,from%20Visa%20and%20ATM%20operators.)):

> ATM surcharge rebates do not apply to any fees other than surcharges assessed for using an ATM to withdraw cash in local currency from your Schwab Bank account.

What kind of fees can using an ATM incur that isn't a surcharge assessed for using an ATM to withdraw cash?

Comment: If you're withdrawing money in a different currency perhaps.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The following action can incur some fee at an ATM, according to the answers by [Robert Longson](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/34139/robert-longson), [Mashtatoes](https://www.reddit.com/user/Mashtatoes) and  [Mysunsai](https://www.reddit.com/user/Mysunsai) from the comment section and [Reddit](https://redd.it/10b4gy4):

Depositing cash. Checking an account balance. Cashing checks. Withdrawing in another currency.

Comment: You could just list anything that can be done with an ATM that is not withdrawing cash in the local currency. But then it would be exactly the sentence in the question, which is why your question got downvoted to begin with.

Comment: @littleadv Sounds like an answer.

Comment: OK, posted. If that's what you're really looking for...

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of fees can using an ATM incur that isn't a surcharge assessed for using an ATM to withdraw cash?

Anything that you can do with an ATM which is not withdrawing cash in the local currency. Note that *cash* can include non-local currency, for that you won't get fees reimbursement.

The list can include anything. You've mentioned checking balances or depositing, but it can be anything and everything, really. Checking the weather, if that's what the ATM allows.

Schwab promised to refund you fees for withdrawing cash in the local currency. Anything else - is on you. *Anything*.

In reality, ATMs are for withdrawing cash. It is unlikely that you'd use a foreign ATM for anything other than withdrawing cash in the local currency. So for all intents and purposes all your fees would be reimbursed. But, to cover Schwab's a$$ets, that's the disclaimer.